# How to determine what feature flags to enable or disable for an architecture

Tags: c++, linux, bash, gcc, cpu-architecture

I have two virtual machines; both are running on identical Intel Xeon E5-2699v4 (Broadwell-EP) platform. However, one virtual machine (the production machine) resides on a host which has of the features disabled, while they're all enabled on the other machine (the build machine). We also have other host machines running on an Intel Xeon E5-2699v3 platform (Haswell-EP) but those hosts will be addressed at a later time. I am able to determine what features are disabled by observing the results from a one-line bash command from my local machine:

```
sort <(sshi vm1 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags | head -n 1 | sed -r 's/\s+/\t/g' | cut -f 3- | sed -r 's/\t/\n/g' | sort | uniq") <(sshi vm2 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags | head -n 1 | sed -r 's/\s+/\t/g' | cut -f 3- | sed -r 's/\t/\n/g' | sort | uniq") | uniq -u
```

...where `sshi` is a bash alias which determines what key file to use when connecting, `vm1` is the hostname of the machine with all of the features enabled and `vm2` is the hostname of the machine which does *not* have all of the features enabled. I would think that this oneline command can then be paired with a loop to generate feature enablement flags for a compiler...

```
for feature in $(...); do echo "-mno-${feature}"; done
```

...which generates a list as such:

> ```
> -mno-abm
> -mno-avx
> -mno-avx2
> -mno-bmi1
> -mno-bmi2
> -mno-eagerfpu
> -mno-fma
> -mno-hle
> -mno-invpcid
> -mno-movbe
> -mno-pcid
> -mno-pse36
> -mno-rtm
> -mno-tsc_adjust
> -mno-xsave
> -mno-xsaveopt
> ```

Taking this list and passing it to the compiler via CMake:

```
LIST(APPEND COMMON_FLAGS /* paste flags here, along with other things such as -Wall -pedantic -Werror=etc */)
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET my_target PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS ${COMMON_FLAGS})
```

...presents compilation errors when using `g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)` provided by package `devtoolset-4` on `Oracle Linux Server 7.3`:

> ```
> c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-bmi1’
> c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-eagerfpu’
> c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-invpcid’
> c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-pcid’
> c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-pse36’
> c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-tsc_adjust’
> ```

That first error can be resolved simply by changing it to `-mno-bmi` instead of `-mno-bmi1`

I did find this interesting tidbit from the [GCC mailing list archive](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2016-07/msg00031.html): `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target`. Using this to search for features does not reveal all of the missing feature flags, so that seems to be a dead end to me.

So my questions are thusly:

1. Why aren't the feature sets directly convertible to feature flags
   for compilers? I would certainly understand if it's a "new" feature
   that the compiler simply doesn't understand or support... but
   changing `-mno-bmi1` to `-mno-bmi` suggests to me that there's
   simply a disagreement of what to name the feature sets.
2. Is there a better method of compiling a fully-optimized build from
   the machine with all features enabled to target the machine with
   some features disabled?
3. Is there a mapping somewhere which describes what feature names are
   reported by the kernel through `/proc/cpuinfo` (or elsewhere) and
   the name used by compilers?